# Sorting contents of .dat file

Tags: sorting, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to use the command prompt of my Windows 10 laptop to sort a .dat file but the error "Input file specified two times" keeps popping up. 
Here's a picture of it. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Edit: Okay, after messing around, I've found the command to sort my .dat files - "sort filename.filetype /o outputfilename.filetype"

But now a new problem has popped up. I'm sorting a bunch of random numbers, ranging from 1 to 10,000. The numbers are sorted, but not in ascending manner, but in Natural Sort Order (ie: 1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 28, 200...) which is not what I'm looking for... Is there anyway to sort in ascending order? [Natural Sort Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjQXt.png)

Comment: I don't believe "-n" is a valid parameter to sort. What does this have to do with python?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp -n will sort the file by numbers

Comment: @B.Cratty Not on my windows 10 box. And "-o" is not an option either.  [Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sort).

Comment: Im running off of linux. My fault @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Sorry, the python tag was a mistake... This is part of a text file to be run on python. My bad! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Where are the numbers in the record? Is this a delimited or fixed-width record? Could you provide a sample of 3-4 records in the question? The Windows sort.exe can do a number of things. What the record looks like will need to be known before a sort.exe solution can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `sort.exe` won't do what you want. However, you have Python, so here's a simple script to do what you need.

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    lines = [int(l) for l in f if l.strip().isdigit()]
    lines.sort()
    print(*lines, sep = "\n")
```

Save it as "psort.py" use it like:

```
python psort.py input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It works and my data is now sorted in ascending order!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sort -o norder.dat > order.dat`

Let me know how it goes!